# When an instance has its -dealloc method called?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class instance with a strong property `SomeClass`, which is referenced only by this single instance. At some point this strong property gets overwritten by a newly created instance, which  assigned to this strong property.

```
@implementation SomeClass

- (instancetype)init;
{
     static NSInteger idx = 0;
     NSLog(@"I am %", idx++);

     self = [super init];
     return self;
}


- (oneway void)dealloc;
{
   NSLog("bye"); 
}
@end
```

Then, in the class holding reference:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeClass *prop;
```

... then

```
self.prop = [[SomeClass alloc] init];   /// first time assigned
```

... and then

```
self.prop = [[SomeClass alloc] init];   /// second time assigned
```

Normally, the sequence is:

- the NEW instance gets allocated (calling its custom -init*)
- the OLD instance gets deallocated (calling its custom -dealloc)

The output would look:

```
 I am 0
 I am 1
 bye
```

But, is it possible that the sequence is reversed ?

Is there any possibility to get an output like this?:

```
 I am 0
 bye
 I am 1
```

For example, if the `SomeClass -init` method performs some CPU heavy task, but still in the same / main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
self.prop = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

the stuff on the right of the equals sign happens before the actual assignment. There is no question of deallocating the existing object until the assignment. Thus, “I am ...” will print before there is any question of deallocating the existing object.

Comment: Will `self.prop = nil;` deallocate the existing object?

Comment: Eventually, yes, if nothing else retains it. But it needn’t happen instantly.